# GCS Says File Already Exists in Bucket But It Doesn't

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a storage bucket to put files in, and I put one video file. Then when I try to add **any other** file, it says the file already exists, but it doesn't. Couldn't find any solutions, or any threads about this. Anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue,

If you are logged in with multiple accounts, and even if you selected the correct account, sometimes GCS thinks you are using a different account and doesn't let you do anything.

Cleared the cookies and it worked. (Or if you don't want to, use a private tab to log in)