# Continuously getting Resolve conflict error while uploading new file or updating existing file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the Google Cloud console to upload files to Storage. My IAM account has full rights to upload files to given bucket, recently I started getting following error while updating existing file, now even I get same error while uploading new file.

[image]

I do not have purchased GCP support, so thought this may be right platform to check if any one has any solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is usually related to an issue with the session's cookies. This [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662299/gcs-says-file-already-exists-in-bucket-but-it-doesnt) about the same issue was answered by the poster. It gave two possible solutions:

- Clear the cookies
- Log in through a private window/tab

On top of those two workarounds, there's another known solution:

- Log out of GCP (with all the accounts if there were many) and log in again